# get-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'CylanceSvc'

Tags: powershell, agent, packer, winrm

I have been tasked with creating a Packer ami from a CIS Windows 2016 Marketplace image. Part of this piece is to include agent installation so that the agents are pre-baked on to the ami. When trying to install Cylance its giving the error:

> get-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'CylanceSvc'.

The code for this installation looks like this:

```
function install-cylance {

        $cylance= get-service -Name CylanceSvc
        Copy-Item \\<IP_address>\Server_Agents\cylance\config.xml -Destination 'C:\Program Files\Cylance\Desktop' -Force
        if(!$cylance) {
            Copy-Item -Path W:\cylance\CylanceProtect_x64.msi -Destination c:\Server_Agents -Force
            c:\Server_Agents\CylanceProtect_x64.msi /q /l*v c:\Server_Agents\CylanceInstall.log PIDKEY=******** LAUNCHAPP=*
            sleep -Seconds 60     
        } 
}


function install-cylanceoptics {

       $cylance= get-service -Name CyOptics

        if(!$cylance) {
            Copy-Item -Path W:\cylance\CylanceOPTICSSetup.exe -Destination c:\Server_Agents -Force
            $command = "C:\Server_Agents\CylanceOPTICSSetup.exe -s"
            Invoke-Expression $command
            sleep -Seconds 20
                    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue is with this or what a different/correct name for the cylance agent might be please?

Any help is appreciated. I'm new to tech.

Comment: Isn't that error to be expected if the service isn't already installed?  Are you trying to suppress the error message and continue with the install if this occurs?  If so, try this instead: `$cylance= get-service -Name CylanceSvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'`

Comment: As @boxdog said, it looks like normal behavior of your script. It checks if the service CylanceSvc exists. If it doesn't, it proceeds with the installation.

It should not break the installation, but simply be a verbose explanation.

Comment: hi @boxdog & P-L thanks for getting back to this post! Ah yes, i see what you mean!  I'm new to PowerShell (had to learn basics in 2 days to be able to do this work). That makes total sense! The error for the installation i am trying to do is actually another part of the log. Thanks again!